# how many childs in my arraycollection with same node in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I have an ArrayCollection which has several employees and departments.
Each employee belongs to one department.

How can I find out how many employees are belonging to the same department from the said ArrayCollection.

In database we use join query to do this, but how can I do this by using an ArrayCollection in Flex?

For Example

```
var employees:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
{Id:1, name="a", departmentid:1},
{Id:1, name="b", departmentid:1},
{Id:1, name="c", departmentid:1},
{Id:1, name="x", departmentid:2},
{Id:1, name="y", departmentid:2},
{Id:1, name="m", departmentid:3},
{Id:1, name="n", departmentid:3},
{Id:1, name="p", departmentid:3},
{Id:1, name="o", departmentid:3},
{Id:1, name="s", departmentid:4}]);
```

in above arraycollection 
3 employees are belonging to department 1
2 employees are belonging to department 2
4 employees are belonging to department 3
1 employees are belonging to department 4

How can i fetch these values from arraycollection in flex?
is there in inbuild function or property provided by adobe.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For Example 
var employees:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
{Id:1, name="a", departmentid:1},
{Id:1, name="b", departmentid:1},
{Id:1, name="c", departmentid:1},
{Id:1, name="x", departmentid:2},
{Id:1, name="y", departmentid:2},
{Id:1, name="m", departmentid:3},
{Id:1, name="n", departmentid:3},
{Id:1, name="p", departmentid:3},
{Id:1, name="o", departmentid:3},
{Id:1, name="s", departmentid:4}]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the built in filter function to filter what you want.
Plus your object was not set up properly.

```
function myFilterFunc( obj:Object ):Boolean{
  if( obj['departmentid'] == deptId )
    return true;
  return false;
}


var deptId:int = 0;
var employees:ArrayCollection;  

employees = new ArrayCollection([
  {'Id':1,'name':"a", 'departmentid':1},
  {'Id':1,'name':"b", 'departmentid':1},
  {'Id':1,'name':"c", 'departmentid':1},
  {'Id':1,'name':"x", 'departmentid':2},
  {'Id':1,'name':"y", 'departmentid':2},
  {'Id':1,'name':"m", 'departmentid':3},
  {'Id':1,'name':"n", 'departmentid':3},
  {'Id':1,'name':"p", 'departmentid':3},
  {'Id':1,'name':"o", 'departmentid':3},
  {'Id':1,'name':"s", 'departmentid':4}]);


employees.filterFunction = myFilterFunc;
trace( employees.length ) // 10 // no filter applied
employees.refresh()
trace( employees.length ) // 0  // default of 0 is applied
deptId = 1
employees.refresh()
trace( employees.length ) // 3
deptId = 2
employees.refresh()
trace( employees.length ) // 2
deptId = 3
employees.refresh()
trace( employees.length ) // 4
deptId = 4
employees.refresh()
trace( employees.length ) // 1


employees.filterFunction = null;
employees.refresh()
trace( employees.length ) // 10
```

Answer (score 0):

In Flex/AS3 it is the same as in any programming language (java,php,c etc).
You have to do a loop into the elements of the array and check the department property.

```
var myColl:ArrayCollection....

var count:int = 0;

for(i=0 ; i < myColl.length; i++)
{
   var emp:MyEmplModel = myColl[i] as MyEmplModel;

   if(emp.department == "someDepartment")
   {
      count++;
   }
}

trace("There are "+count+" emp. in someDepartment");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the chields is again ArrayCollection the follow might help ..

```
var o : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
( o.getItemAt( 0 ) as ArrayCollection ).length
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Adrian pointed out, you need to implement an algorithm for parsing your collection, and determine how many employees belong to each department. Some ideas to go about this:

Normally, array collections are used to store multiple items of the same type, so it doesn't make sense to have employees and departments in the same collection. Since the departments in any company are usually well-defined, in a sense that they don't change very often, it is best to use an 'enum', or a list of constants, with each department name, or unique code. This can be achieved by creating a static class, which contains all the department names as static strings.

The next step is to parse your initial collection, and determine how many employees are assigned to each of the existing departments. Again, Adrian pointed out a way to implement this.

Hope this helps. Have a great day.